# How prove this number of the methods is this $\prod\prod 4\cos^2{\frac{j\pi}{m+1}}+4\cos^2{\frac{k\pi}{n+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

> show that an $m$-by-$n$ chessboard can be partitioned some $1$-by-$2$ the numbers of methods is
>   $$\prod_{j=1}^{\lfloor\dfrac{m}{2}\rfloor}\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\rfloor}
> \left(4\cos^2{\dfrac{j\pi}{m+1}}+4\cos^2{\dfrac{k\pi}{n+1}}\right)？$$

Maybe this is famous problem,But I can't find it.and we easy to prove $m,n\le 5$ is true.and for general I can't prove  it

Comment: I've removed the `\left` and `\right` from the title because they cause unnecessary spacing wich results in a line wrap on the front page.

Comment: By $[m/2]$ do you by chance mean the floor or ceiling function? And if so, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There gives references in this wikipage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling

Comment: oh,nice!thank you give usefull